# Deploy docker image as standalone executable

Tags: docker

Are there any tools to install/deploy a docker image as a standalone/portable installation. 
So that you don't have to install docker manually beforehand, just one installation, and it will run and deploy your docker image. And perhaps autostart it as well on boot.

Mainly interested for Win&OSX, but for linux would be nice too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that this is even possible. Docker has so many dependencies.

- (Linux &/ OSX)
  The much easier way would be a bash script wich starts the installation and afterwards runs the container. Shouldn't be that time consuming.

Answer (score -1):

Someone tried:

https://github.com/rzane/docker2exe

I don't know if this works or worked - the project looks dead.